# Не могу открыть браузер в режиме ('--headless')

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

У меня есть код на python. Я открываю браузер с режимом "headless", закрываю его. Мне нужно опять открыть с режимом "headless", но он открывается просто как обычный браузер. Код ниже:

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# создаем браузер
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',
                           options=chrome_options)
                           
# открываем сайт
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
# закрываем браузер
browser.close()

# Открываем браузер заново
browser.start_session({})  # ПРОБЛЕМА ТУТ
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
browser.close()
```

Нашел полуфикс проблемы: Каждый раз создавать новую переменную с открытием браузера с "headless" режимом. И каждый раз после всех действий его закрывать (quit())

Comment: попробуйте `--headless` -> `headless` то есть убрать два минуса

Comment: не работает, там функция start_session({}) почему-то не открывает браузер с нужными параметрами.